# type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<DateTime, List<Event>>'

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I'm trying to convert a Future list into a LinkedHashMap and I'm having But I'm returning a  Future Dynamic

This is my class

```
class Event {
  final String calendarDatesStart;
  final String eventTitle;

  const Event(this.calendarDatesStart, this.eventTitle, );

  @override
  String toString() => eventTitle;
}

// Gets the Future
var datasource = const FutureCalendarEvents();

getCalendarDataSource() async {
  return await datasource.getCalendarFuture();
}
```

My function to return the Map

```
// Add dates to eventsMap ??
myDates () async {

  var eventsMap = <DateTime, List<Event>>{};
  List myDatesEvents = await getCalendarDataSource();

  for(var item in myDatesEvents){
    print(item);
    eventsMap.update(DateTime(item.calendarDatesStart), 
item.calendarEventName);
  }
    return eventsMap;
}
```

And here is where it takes my events

```
// Takes my events
final kEvents = LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<Event>>(
  equals: isSameDay,
  hashCode: getHashCode,
)..addAll(eventsMap);
```

And this is what I end up with

[image]

Thanks for any help I've been at this a long time trying to work it out.

This is the plugin on Flutter I'm trying to work with https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar

Comment: How does it even compile?

Comment: It complies but just returns an empty  map

Comment: I think there's 2 things, First you're missing an `await` in some point. Second don't just use `List` class specify the Generic type like what `getCalanderFuture()` return?
Is this code in Github? So I can test it before solve it

Comment: you must use await to get future variable